# iis 8.5 forms authentication with <location> tag

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

I have a site running in IIS. The default document is default.aspx. The site is secured using Forms Authentication. I have a folder called .com/Public where I want anonymous users to be directed. The .com/default.aspx page does a response.redirect() in the page.load to .com/Public/home.aspx. I have a separate web.config in the .com/Public folder allowing anonymous access.
When a user goes to .com, they get redirected to the Login page .com/Person/login.aspx instead of .com/Public/home.aspx
Here is .com/web.config Forms Authentication bit:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".TTCookie" timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Person/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Person/Home.aspx" path="/" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

.com/default.aspx is added as a location to the main web.config to allow access (at the end of the web.config)

```
 <location path="Default.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Why does the User not get directed to .com/Public/home.aspx? Is there any other way I can achieve this? This configuration works on my local machine (VS2010) but not on the webserver (IIS 8.5)

Comment: try to change `?` to `*` in  `<location path="Default.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>` and also remove  `allow users` from `system.web`

Comment: No, didn't change it. here is what's in the config file sections now:
<code>  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".TrenTraceCookie" timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Person/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Person/Home.aspx" path="/" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <!-- SET UP AUTHORIZATION USING LOCATION TAG -->
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration></code>

Comment: sorry for the bad format, can't seem to change it.

Comment: you dont keep location in `system.web` try to bring it out and give seperately

Comment: It is already outside:
`code`    
  <!-- SET UP AUTHORIZATION USING LOCATION TAG -->
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>    `code`

Comment: Do you mean like this?
</system.web>
  <!-- SET UP AUTHORIZATION USING LOCATION TAG -->
  <location path="Default.aspx">
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
  </location>
</configuration>

Comment: yes!! did you try that way

Comment: Just tried and I get a misformed configuration file error: The configuration section 'authorization' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: please do one thing try to keep you web config into Qst so that easy to rectify for me ,

Comment: Here is all of the location section:

  <!-- SET UP AUTHORIZATION USING LOCATION TAG -->
  <location path="Default.aspx">
     <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
It is at the very end of the web.config, just </configuration> after it

Comment: And the Authentication piece:
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".TTCookie" timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Person/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Person/Home.aspx" path="/" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>